# ActionChain moves YouTube playlist index item up to the desired index location, but never accurately downward?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, youtube

I am attempting to use Selenium (my first time working with it) to reorder YouTube playlist items based on their index values, but for whatever reason downward moves in index go to different locations than specified.

Meaning if I want to move the 1st item in the list to the 5th index positionit will actually end up being moved to the 10th position.

But upward moves work just fine i.e. going to the 10th position to 2nd.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True) # Keep the browser open after the script finishes
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir=C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data") ## Path to your chrome profile
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list= xxxx ") ## insert test playlist Id

# find all the index-container elements by their xpath
indexes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//ytd-playlist-video-renderer//*[@id='index-container']")

# get the first and the fifth index-container elements
first_index = indexes[0]
fifth_index = indexes[4]

# Print the items at each location
print("First index-container element:")
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='video-title']").get_attribute("textContent"))
print()
print("Fifth index-container element:")
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@id='video-title'])[4]").get_attribute("textContent"))

# create an action chain object
action = ActionChains(driver)

# drag and drop the first index-container element to the fifth index-container element
action.click_and_hold(first_index).pause(2).move_to_element(fifth_index).release().perform()
# action.drag_and_drop(first_index, fifth_index).perform()
```

I have tried using offsets, changing click_and_hold to drag_and_drop, using delays (WebDriverWait, pauses), scrollIntoView and even some ChatGPT compensations for lazy loading and javascript interactions to no avail. I am running matching versions of Chrome for Testing & ChromeDriver.

The above code will consistently grab the correct video and move it... it just won't move it correctly in both directions.

I am new to Selenium and it wouldn't surprise me if it was a simple fix, but at this point I am stumped.

FWIW - The above code is intended to reference a YouTube playlist that you are logged in and have editing capabilities of.